# Search query, 'order by' priority

Tags: sql-server, search-engine

I need implement simple search in small content table: id, name, description, content.
Results must be order by priorities

1. name
2. description
3. content

it's mean that if searched word was found in description field, it will be shown only after all rows that have dog in name field

**What I did:**

I tried create temp table with structure like table that I use but with another field priority. for each field, these I use for search, do **insert select** to temp table

**Example:**

```
  DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(255)


  CREATE TABLE #tbl_search
    (
      [id] INT NOT NULL ,
      [name] NVARCHAR(255) ,
      [description] NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
      [content] NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
      [priority] INT
    )    


    --searching in name field
  INSERT    INTO #tbl_search
            ( [ID] ,
              [name] ,
              [description] ,
              [content] ,
              [priority]

            )
            SELECT  [ID] ,
                    [name] ,
                    [description] ,
                    [content] ,
                    1
            FROM    [tbl_content]
            WHERE   name LIKE '%' + @query + '%'

    --searching in description field            
  INSERT    INTO #tbl_search
            ( [ID] ,
              [name] ,
              [description] ,
              [content] ,
              [priority]

            )
            SELECT  [ID] ,
                    [name] ,
                    [description] ,
                    [content] ,
                    2
            FROM    [tbl_content]
            WHERE   description LIKE '%' + @query + '%'
                    AND id NOT IN ( SELECT  id
                                    FROM    #tbl_search )
   --.....           

  SELECT    *
  FROM      #tbl_search
  ORDER BY  [priority]

  DROP TABLE #tbl_search
```

Comment: So, is there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: i guess he's asking, how would u do it..

Comment: Am, yes you right, that's a question :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way of doing it would be using the [CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) keyword:

```
SELECT name, description, content,
    priority = CASE
        WHEN name LIKE '%' + @query + '%' THEN 1
        WHEN desription LIKE '%' + @query + '%'  THEN 2
        WHEN content LIKE '%' + @query + '%'  THEN 3
    END CASE
FROM tbl_content
WHERE
    name LIKE '%' + @query + '%' OR
    desription LIKE '%' + @query + '%'  OR
    content LIKE '%' + @query + '%'
ORDER BY priority ASC
```

Comment: interesting, i did not know that i have option for searching in select

Comment: @msony, now u do :)  `CASE` is a very powerful tool

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to use UNION query:

```
SELECT name AS text FROM tbl_content WHERE name LIKE '%' + @query + '%'
UNION
SELECT description AS text FROM tbl_content WHERE desription LIKE '%' + @query + '%'
UNION
SELECT content AS text FROM tbl_content WHERE content LIKE '%' + @query + '%'
```

Comment: @msony I believe you won't get duplicates, unless you use UNION ALL.

Comment: he will get duplicates, cause the query contains only 1 coloum. @Alex, you need to add all 3 column to each query (and leave the condition as is).

Answer (score 0):

For sake of completeness, I move @Amirshk brilliant solution to the next level by using the case when in order clause (query for mysql):

```
SELECT name, description, content
FROM tbl_content
WHERE
    name LIKE '%' + @query + '%' OR
    desription LIKE '%' + @query + '%'  OR
    content LIKE '%' + @query + '%'
ORDER BY CASE
        WHEN name LIKE '%' + @query + '%' THEN 1
        WHEN desription LIKE '%' + @query + '%'  THEN 2
        WHEN content LIKE '%' + @query + '%'  THEN 3
    END
```

Comment: what's the effective difference here?

Comment: The original solution adds priority column to the results and orders the results by priority. Though the mysql order accepts `CASE` statement. In my answer there is no need to add the priority column. The ordering of the result is the same as the original answer.