# Mysql search, order according to priority

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, search

I decided that I wanted a search field on my website, the thing is I don't really have any knowledge about search algorithms. The search box works like you can enter any number of names(username, firstname, lastname) or emails separating each by a space. So I came up with the following using codeigniter's active record class (it's very simple):

```
    $emails = FALSE;
    $names = FALSE;

    foreach($search_array as $value){
        if(valid_email($value)){
            $emails[] = $value;
        } else{
            $names[] = $value;
        }
    }

    if($emails){
        $this->db->where_in('email', $emails);
        if($names){
            $this->db->or_where_in('username', $names);
            $this->db->or_where_in('firstname', $names);
            $this->db->or_where_in('lastname', $names);
        }
    } else{
        if($names){
            $this->db->where_in('username', $names);
            $this->db->or_where_in('firstname', $names);
            $this->db->or_where_in('lastname', $names);
        }
    }

    $this->db->select('id, username, firstname, lastname');
    $query = $this->db->get('users');

    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        return $query->result();            
    }

    return FALSE;
```

What this code does is running a bunch of where statements and then simply sending it all back. 
Perhaps I could clean up the if-statements and how the email works, but that's not the point. This code works perfectly (at least with a very small database :P) but I want it to do more:

- Right now you need to enter the correct name or email to get any good result. If your almost right it would be nice to get some suggestions but that I probably can figure that out by myself doing some LIKE.
- I want to sort the whole result array, and here is where I'm stumbling. Since both the email and the username is unique I want a search to display using the following priorities:

  1. Email
  2. Username
  3. Firstname + Lastname
  4. Firstname
  5. Lastname

Well for the time being I don't really care about for example Email+username+firstname+lastname since I believe that would be way to overwhelming :P

I did found this topic [Search query, 'order by' priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260909/search-query-order-by-priority) but since I don't know which is what in my search it didn't really help me but perhaps I could use something similar?

Anyway you guys know a way to solve the priority problem? Have I perhaps missed some major functions that could help? And what will happen when my database goes big? ;)

Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
ORDER BY email != 'value',
         username != 'value',
         firstname != 'value' AND lastname != 'value',
         firstname != 'value',
         lastname != 'value'
```

If the expression is false (meaning they are the same) then it's equal to 0 and will sort higher than an expression that is true (meaning they are different) which equals 1 and sorts after a 0.

If you find the != confusing then this is the same thing:

```
ORDER BY email = 'value' DESC,
         username = 'value' DESC,
         firstname = 'value' AND lastname = 'value' DESC,
         firstname = 'value' DESC,
         lastname = 'value' DESC
```

Comment: I'm not quite following actually. What do you mean with 'value'? Where does it come from? I suppose you mean I should replace it with something, if so replace with what? I also don't really see how I would do the firstname+lastname pritority (when a firstname and a lastname match to same id)

Comment: 'value' is the search value entered by the user. I will edit the answer to include firstname + lastname.

Comment: First of I'm not sure if I was clear, you can search for e.g. multiple emails. Will it still work? Second, I still don't quite understand (and this might me related to the first question). Since 'value' is a string(or array, which should I use?) how would the equal work? Does it check every item if it's equal to the email field?

Comment: Okey I think I know the answer to my first question, it will still work right?

Comment: If it's an array, your codeigniter converts it to the SQL: `email IN ('value1','value2',etc)` so then you do the same in the `ORDER BY`. You would probably have an easier time if you wrote the SQL yourself, since you just copy each `WHERE` clause to the `ORDER BY`. (I personally don't like, and never use, active records for the simple reason that I *always* run into things they can't do. Although I am aware that they make the code easy and fast to write.)

Comment: Ahh, now I understand at least to the level that some trial and error will make me understand! And yes you are probably right about the SQL. Thank you so much! :D

Comment: For the `email IN` don't forget to sort `DESC` or it will be in reverse order.

Comment: I was looking to perform a similar query (sorting books according to a predefined list of formats), and this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.